# Handling empty string input leading to segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm encoding the contents of a message struct into a buffer.

```
int encode(const struct message *msg, unsigned char *buffer, size_t max_size)
{
  if (buffer == NULL)
    return -1;

  unsigned char *buf_pos = buffer;
  unsigned char *ep = buffer + max_size;

  if (buf_pos + 1 <= ep) {
    *buf_pos++ = SYNC_WORD_1;
  } else {
    return buf_pos - buffer;
  }
  .
  .
  .
}
```

When I call `encode(&message, "", 1024);` I encounter a segmentation fault as expected. My understanding is that the segfault is caused by an attempt to access memory not allocated to the program, since `""` will contain just the null terminator and I'm passing it in place of a pointer.

The problem I'm having is when I try to handle this error. I haven't found a way to identify the invalid input that doesn't either cause a false-positive with valid inputs or another segfault.

So what's the correct way to weed out this kind of input?

Comment: How about `strlen(buffer)==0`

Comment: There's no way in general to solve the problem of knowing how much memory, and whether it is writable, exists at a certain memory location.

Comment: `When I call encode(&message, "", 1024); ` The second argument is a string constant, which cannot be written to. Your `*buf_pos++ = SYNC_WORD_1;` attempts to write to it.

Comment: joop is correct. You are not passing in 0, but a valid pointer that points to a zero byte. That zero byte is, however, in a read only page, so you get a segfault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done.

You're basically asking "given a pointer, how can I ensure that there are n byets of writable space there?" which is a question C doesn't help you with.

This is, at its root, because pointers are just addresses, there is no additional meta information of the kind you're after associated with each pointer value.

You can check the pointer for being `NULL`, but that's basically the only pointer value you can be certain is invalid. Non-portably (on embedded targets especially) you can get clever and check if the pointer is in various known non-writable regions, but that's still very coarse.

Comment: the question is how to avoid the seg fault event.  This is not an answer to that question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are not checking the size of the buffer when you copy it in buf_pos
When trying to access buf_pos + 1, you may going into some memory you don't have acces to, causing a segmentation fault. 
Did you try usung valgrind on your executable ?

Answer (score 0):

When asking a question about a runtime problem, as this question is doing, post the actual input, the expected output, the actual output and most importantly, post code code that cleanly compiles, is short, and still exhibits the problem.

The following code will handle a pointer to a string that only contains a NUL byte.

However, that is not the only problem.  What if the passed in buffer pointer may be pointing to a char array in read only memory, then the posted code would still result in a seg fault event.

```
int encode(const struct message *msg, unsigned char *buffer, size_t max_size)
{
    if (buffer == NULL)
        return -1;

    if( strlen(buffer) == 0 )
        return -1;

    unsigned char *buf_pos = buffer;
    unsigned char *ep = buffer + max_size;

    if (buf_pos + 1 <= ep)
    {
        *buf_pos++ = SYNC_WORD_1;
    }

    else
    {
        return buf_pos - buffer;
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

To be able to help you more, you need to post the scenarios under which this function will be called.